# Passing 2D array to function

Tags: c++, arrays

i have a problem. I'am creating a matrix calculator. What do I want is to choose the size of the matrix. I have two 2D arrays (a) and (b).I'am filling the arrays with integres. The problem is that the integres(my constants that i save in to the arrays) doesnt came out, only the positions that they are at. It's just that the pointers seems to not Dereference. Dont know what is wrong.

```
void rotater(int* a,int* b,int select)
{        
    int* matrix;

    if(select == 1)
    {
        for(int d = 0; d < i; d++)
        {
            for(int c = 0; c < j; c++)
            {
                cout << *(a+c) << *(a+d) << " "; 
                //if i choose the size as 2x2 this comes out as a 
                //matrix {11,12;21,22} just as positions not my 
                //numbers that i choose
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    else  if(select == 2)
    {
        for(int d = 0; d < y; d++)
        {
            for(int c = 0; c < x; c++)
            {
                cout << *(b+d) <<*(b+c) <<" ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }   
}

int a[i][j];
int b[x][y];
int *matrix1 = &a[0][0];    
int *matrix2 = &b[0][0];

cout << endl;
cout << "Choose_matrix: " << "(1,2,both)" << endl;
cin >> matrix;

f = matrix //I have function that changes char matrix to int f

cout << endl;
cout << "Choose_operand: " << "(rotr,rotl,+,-,*,/,diag)" << endl;
cin >> operand;

e = operand // I have function that changes char operand to int e

switch(e)
{
case 1:
    rotater(matrix1, matrix2, f); // calling function with 3 parameters 
    break;

default:
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you add main to your example? So it can be compiled and also show results vs what you expected.

Comment: Your indices are not calculated correctly. For example use `b[c + d * x]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### C-Style Code

First off, you are using C++, so you should avoid using C style arrays, and raw pointers wherever possible. I would recommend either using `std::vector<int>`, or, because you want a constant size, `std::array<int>`.

### Redundant Code

I don't see why you are including two arrays in your `rotater` function. You have the same logic for each parameter, there is a lot of redundant code there.

### Parameter Type

Your parameters in `rotater` are asking for an `int*`, but when you call the function, you give it an `int[][]` which is a different data type.

### Working Example

All that being said, You have a lot of stuff going on in your code that don't have clear functions. On top of this, you didn't include a `main()` function, so I can't compile your code. If it were me, I would run your program through a debugger to see what is going on a little more in depth. Here is what I believe you are going for.

```
#include <iostream>

void matrix_display(int *mat, const int x_size, const int y_size)
{
    for ( int x = 0; x < x_size; x++ )
    {
        for ( int y = 0; y < y_size; y++ )
        {
            std::cout << *(mat + x) << *(mat + y) << " ";
        }
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    const int X_SIZE = 2;
    const int Y_SIZE = 2;
    int matrix[X_SIZE*Y_SIZE] = {4, 7, 3, 7};

    matrix_display(matrix, X_SIZE, Y_SIZE);

    return 0;
}
```

again, if it were me, I would be using an `std::array<std::array<int, 2>, 2>` rather than an `int*`

Comment: Well, I new at C++ I have a little knowledge from C, but ill try what you suggest and post the result, thanks.

Comment: Are you sure ` std::cout << *(mat + x) << *(mat + y) << " ";` is right?